# parse analysis installation issue, two function ParseInstallion and PushService

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

`ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();`

`PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YourActivity.class);`

At Parse.com official website, I want to use parse analysis. It seems to need installation before use. I want to know what difference of these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a misleading statement in the documentation

From: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/507987575990925/

> As a workaround, please try taking out the call to "ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground()" in your onCreate(). This call is unnecessary, since all of the push-related calls that manipulate the installation class (like PushService.subscribe) already call the necessary save calls on the installation object.